# Get raw element from d3 selection

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svg, d3.js

I'm building a custom visual for Power BI, written in TypeScript. In my class' constructor I write `this.svg = d3.select(this.target).append("svg").attr("id", "svg");` (`this.target` just holds a standard HTML element, it's not important for the question).

My question is ,using `this.svg`, how can I obtain just the raw SVG element? From Googling it seems I should be able to use `this.svg.node()`, but there must be something subtle going on that makes this different to the "true" element...

When I run `console.log(this.svg.node())`, its output appears exactly the same as `console.log(document.getElementById("svg"))` in Chrome's developer window, so that's fine.

However, using the expression `this.svg.node().getBoundingClientRect()` causes my TypeScript to not compile because of the error `Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'Node'`, whereas `document.getElementById("svg").getBoundingClientRect()` returns the correct value.

How do I just get the true, raw DOM element that `this.svg` refers to?

I'm using d3 v3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.node()` is returning the real element, the problem here is that in other situations `.node()` can return other types of objects than just `Element`s, so the typescript compiler can't know it'll definitely have the `getBoundingClientRect()` function.

The solution is to cast the object as type `Element`:

```
var svgElement = this.svg.node() as Element;
var boundingRect = svgElement.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: There's no such `as` operator to cast in JavaScript… am I missing something?

Comment: `as` is an operator in TypeScript. The issue in the question wasn't a Javascript problem but a TypeScript one, the compiler wouldn't compile because it couldn't assume that `.node()` is an `Element`.